# Filling grid/array randomly

Tags: php, algorithm

I've array MxN of zeros (0). I need to fill it with 20 truths (1) by random postions.

An example

```
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 
1 1 0 1 1 0 0
```

I fill it by non-determine algorithm:

```
$amountUnits = 20;
while($amountUnits > 0) {
    $i = rand(0, $M-1);
    $j = rand(0, $N-1);

    if(!$grid[$i][$j]) {
        $grid[$i][$j] = 1;
        $amountUnits--;
    }
}
```

But it's solved in random time. How can I fill it throught seed or something else? And where I can read about this problem?

Please excuse my bad English.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated**

So it turns out that PHP has a [shuffle](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function, and @jspit's answer shows you how to use it. His answer is the php way to implement my answer.

---

**Original Answer**

Fill the array with 0's, and then add all of the 1's in the first rows and columns. So if you have an array that's 4 rows and 5 columns, and you want 7 1's, it would look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Now, do a [Fischer-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to distribute the 1's around randomly.

Normally, you do that shuffle on a 1-dimensional array. But you can map a 1-dimensional array index to two dimensions with some simple arithmetic, as shown below in pseudo-code. (Sorry, but I'm not really fluent in php.)

```
// shuffle a 2-dimensional array
for (i = numRows * numCols; i > 1; --i)
    j = random(0, i)  // picks a number from 0 to i-1

    // get row and column for i
    irow = (i-1) / numCols  
    icol = (i-1) % numCols

    // get row and column for j
    jrow = j / numCols
    jcol = j % numCols

    // and swap the items
    temp = array[irow, icol]
    array[irow, icol] = array[jrow, jcol]
    array[jrow, jcol] = temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Fill a 1-dimensional array x times with 1 and the rest with 0. shuffle () shuffles the array.
array_chunk divides the array so that a matrix (a 2-dimensional array) is created.

```
$rows = 7;
$cols = 7;
$fillTrue = 20;

$arr = array_fill(0,$fillTrue,1)+array_fill($fillTrue, $rows*$cols-$fillTrue,0);
shuffle($arr);
$arr = array_chunk($arr,$cols);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could do this (since it's really just a chopped up string of random digits?):

```
function truths(int $truths, int $many): array {
    $facts = array_fill(0, $truths, true);
    $statements = array_fill(0, $many, false);

    foreach ($statements as $assertion => $statement) {
        $statements[$assertion] = $facts[$assertion] ?? false;
    }

    shuffle($statements);

    return $statements;
}
```

Then you give a function the number of truths and grid dimensions, and it will generate the output:

```
function truth_grid(int $truths, int $rows, int $columns) {
    return chunk_split(implode(' ', array_map('intval',
        truths($truths, $rows * $columns)
    )), $columns * 2);
}
```

Given:

```
$set = [[4, 3, 3], [10, 4, 5], [12, 3, 9], [5, 2, 10],];

foreach($set as [$truths, $rows, $columns]) {
    print_r(
        sprintf('%d of %d x %d', $truths, $rows, $columns).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.
        truth_grid($truths, $rows, $columns).PHP_EOL
    );
}
```

The readout of which is:

```
4 of 3 x 3

1 0 0 
1 0 1 
1 0 0

10 of 4 x 5

1 0 0 0 1 
0 1 0 0 1 
1 1 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 1

12 of 3 x 9

0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 
1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1

5 of 2 x 10

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
```

And if you're looking for chunked arrays of the same shape:

```
function truth_chunks(int $truths, int $rows, int $columns) {
    return array_chunk(truths($truths, $rows * $columns), $columns);
}
```